# Google App Engine Quota Usage not Showing up Anymore

Tags: google-app-engine

For the last one week I have not been able to see my real time quota usage on Google App Engine. This was something I could easily do before.

Now I have to wait for 2 days - and then it will show on my **Quota Usage History** Page.

How can I enable my real time Quota usage again? This is a recent behavior I've noticed in my Google App Engine - Java - Project.

This is what it looks like when I go to my Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: I saw such results when my app wasn't getting any requests and no app instances were running. Is your app actually running?

Comment: yes my app is running.

Comment: I have the same issue.  It was working earlier in the day, and after working with my app (and consuming a significant amount of resources), it stopped showing stats regarding how much of the quotas have been consumed.

Comment: It magically resolved itself today. So that's great! I guess it was a bug on Google App Engine. Did it get resolved for you @BB

Comment: Yes, it's now working as expected. Thanks for the update @Savio Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

This was more like a bug on Google App Engine Page since the problem resolved itself today magically.

Not a bug